# Angular class instance is giving object instance in production build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm using **Angular 8**

In the application, I have an array of objects to render data accordingly in the HTML

```
public components = [
  {
    type: "button",
    data: {
      label: "Click here"
    }
  },
  {
    type: "description_box",
    data: {
      content: "Enter description"
    }
  }
]
```

Now there are two buttons **Add Button** and **Add Description Box** when the user clicks on the button, the requested object is pushed to the `components` array which is handled like

```
onClick(component: string) {
  switch(component) {
    case 'button': data = new Button(); break;
    case 'description_box': data = new DescriptionBox(); break;
  }

  this.components.push({
    type: this.getTypeFromData(data),
    data: data
}

/**
 * spit class constructor name in lowercase underscored
 * Ex: DescriptionBox -> description_box
 */
private getTypeFromData(data) {
  const className = data.constructor.name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

  let componentType = '';
  for (const name of className) {
    componentType += name + '_';
  }

  return componentType.toLowerCase().slice(0, -1);
}
```

The two classes are like

`components.ts`

```
export class Button {
  label: string;
  color: {
    label: string;
    button: string;
    border: string;
  };
  link: string;
}

export class DescriptionBox {
  text = 'New Title';
}
```

This works fine in the local development, but it is not working as expected in the production build.

**In the production build, the class instance is giving `o` object instead of the class instance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happends because of your classes got minified, so it would take less space. istead of checking `constructor.name` you can check it with `data instanceof DescriptionBox` instead.

Comment: Also the instance of `Button` class is blank object `o {}` while for description box, it is `o {text: "New Title"}`. Is this because the `Button` class properties are not initialized?

Comment: no, the class is renamed to a shorter version. minimizer named it `o`

Comment: If I use `data instanceof DescriptionBox`, it returns boolean, So I will have to write multiple `if-else` statements for each instance check. I tested and the above works for the boolean check. But inside `getTypeFromData` method, I'm generating name from the instance type. Is there any way to get the instanceof name as string?

Comment: class names are lost in the process of minifying. if you want to have some strings you can try something like `class Button { static name = 'Button';...}` and then find this string like `const str = [Button, Box, Anyting].find(cl => data instanceof cl).name`